# How to compare two columns in SQL Redshift using a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, case

I'm trying to find a way to check if two values are the same or not in two different columns using sql redshift

Here is what I've tried:

```
CASE
WHEN table_1.column_a = table_2.column_b THEN 'Match'
ELSE 'No match'
END AS Does_it_match?
```

table_1 and table_2 are joined but it keeps returning the error 'No value specified for parameter 1'
Is it possible to do this kind of CASE statement with sql redshift? If not, is there another way around it?

Comment: The error does not seem related to the sql fragment you have shown - you should not be using a string literal as a column alias.

Comment: My bad that was an error when copying the sql in, however, the error is still the same.

Comment: What happens if you quote the alias `"Does_it_match?"`

Comment: Yes, because the `?` denotes a parameter placeholder, hence your error.